# How to test relationship between a continuous independent variable and a categorical dependent variable?

Tags: anova, multinomial-logit

I have a quite common issue. I would like to test whether the waiting time at a restaurant is related to customer satisfaction ratings.

The independent variable is continuous: waiting time. The dependent variable is categorical: customer satisfaction ratings of Happy, Unhappy, Not answered.

1. Can I use one-way ANOVA? There will be 3 groups (Happy, Unhappy, Not answered) and each group has customers' waiting times. However, in this case, it sounds like the independent variable is the categorical one (ratings) and the dependent variable is continuous (waiting time). Does ANOVA care which is independent, which is dependent?
2. Or, can I use multinomial logistic regression? Then how do I tell if there indeed exists a relationship between the waiting time and the target (ratings)? Check whether there's a positive coefficient?

Your advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: From the perspective of a probability model (like ANOVA or logistic regression), there is no "independent variable" in this setting.  It's an *observational study* in which both waiting time and satisfaction rating are observed.  It can therefore be effective to consider ways to *quantify the degree of association* rather than limiting your forms of analysis to regression-like models where satisfaction is the response.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear you should use some form of logistic regression, the real question is which form would be best.  You have "happy", "not happy", and "not answered".

Three options:  1) Ignore the "not answered" and use the usual logistic regression.  2) Treat "not answered" as intermediate between the other two and use ordinal logistic. 3) Treat "not answered" as fundamentally different and use multinomial logistic.

But I might not do any of these!  People who answer these forms tend to be either very happy or very unhappy, usually about some specific thing. I would use the forms that way. Try to find out why they were happy or unhappy.  I'm guessing that a very long wait time is one cause of unhappiness, but only one. Maybe they got the order completely wrong. Maybe the food was cold. Maybe the waiter was rude. Maybe their seats were uncomfortable. Who knows?  Any sort of statistical analysis of your questions might obscure this. However, if you do wind up doing an analysis, I would include a spline of wait time, because I think it's very likely that the relationship is nonlinear.  Also, I don't think wait time would be related to "happy" responses. People won't check happy just because they didn't wait (at least, not at most places).

Comment: Re "it's pretty clear:" perhaps, but at the very least we should inquire into the possibility of appreciable measurement error in the waiting time.  How is that known?  By asking the customer, maybe?